# Как установить отступ только для <h1> внутри <header/>, и убрать у ссылок подчеркивание?

Tags: html, css

```css
body{
    margin: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.nav li{
    margin-top: 20px; 
    padding-left: -5px;
    padding-top: -5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.nav {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    padding: 0;
}
header {
    background-color: black;
    height: 90px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #3d3d3d;
}
header ul.name {
    background-color: #3d3d3d;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
header h1 {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
hr {
    margin: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 150px;
}
```

```html
        <header>
            <ul class="name">
                <h1>AutoService</h1>
            </ul>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><h2><a href="#">Каталог<a/><h2></li>
                <li><h2><a href="#">Корзина<a/><h2></li>
                <li><h2><a href="#">Контакты<a/><h2></li>
                <li><h2><a href="#">О нас<a/><h2></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <hr width="1" size="700" class="hr">
```

Comment: уточните вопрос - что именно надо сделать?

Comment: Убрать отступ нужно у <header>. Что бы отступ был только у текста, и еще как убрать подчеркивание у ссылок, text-decoration не работает почему-то.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav {
    line-height: (размер отступа);
}
```

Comment: мне надо отступ для h1 в header, а убрать подчеркивания для ссылок в нав баре

Comment: @Alexeyka123 Декорацию ссылок я убрал везде) А чтобы сделать высоту между строками в header пропиши по моему образцу только с классом name

Comment: спасибо, проблема решена!

Comment: @Alexeyka123 Я рад) Удачи